# Wrong page loading by default on firebase link. How do I change the default page that loads? | Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

**Question**

I just set up firebase. However, when I load the link that firebase provided it gives me an 'Error 404'. Now I know that the website is hosted correctly, because when I ran the local host, I then entered the following extension on the end of the url: '/html/index.html' - and it worked.

However, firebase is not finding the correct page to load.

How can I change the page that loads by default, when someone visits my website?

*For context*

I am pretty sure I know what firebase is doing here. When I first ran the local host, it was running the default index.html that firebase provided. Now that I have deleted that default index.html. It doesn't know where to look to find the page to run.

My index.html is within a folder that is within the public folder. The name of that internal folder is html.

This is the current set up of the file structure and my attempt to fix the problem so far (based on advice of Renaud):

[image]

**Update**

I have now implemented the following, but it is loading #404

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `firebase.json` file which is at the root of your project directory

Comment: This is all that is in there: {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "PROJECT ALPHAX",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the doc for [Hosting configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), in order to redirect the traffic to your `index.html` page (**or to another html file**), you need to add the following to the `firebase.json` file which is at the root of your project directory:

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

OR

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/mySpecificHomePage.html"
      }
    ]
  },
```

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public), "the `public` attribute specifies which directory to deploy to Firebase Hosting. The default value is a directory named `public`, but you can specify any directory's path, as long as it exists in your project directory."

---

#### Update following your update (screenshot of your Firebase project file structure):

If I am not mistaking you should do as follows:

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "html",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Note that `rewrites` is within `hosting`!

Comment: {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "PROJECT ALPHAX",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
    
  },
  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/html/index.html"
  }]
}
(I wrote this, not working yet though)

Comment: Can you add to your question a screenshot of yoru Firebase project file structure?

Comment: Sure, will do now

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure to understand you last two comments! :-) "This has been completed" & "Not sure what you mean". I mean see the update I've done to my answer.

Comment: It says html does not exist though :)

Comment: I added the latest picture of everything, the deployment is blocked by the latest change

Comment: What if you do "public": "PROJECT ALPHAX/html"?

Comment: says that it doesn't exist

Comment: Ok so implemented 'projectAlpha/PROJECT ALPHAX/html that allowed the deployment, but still loading a 404. I will update the question again with the latest

Comment: I would start with a brand new Firebase project and avoid having folder names with spaces. It is difficult for me to help you anymore as it seems you kind of modified quite a lot the initial file structure. The `firebase.json` file shall be at the root for example.