# Fiebase hosted url not working after deploying it again

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have update my already deployed flutter project and deployed it again in firebase . It shows the deployment is complete ,but my hosted url leads me to a firebase documentation page like below :

[image]

I intially typed:

```
firebase init 
firebase deploy
```

The url was working fine when I deployed it for the first time . I
made some updation on my project and tried to deployed it again .What can I do now ?

this is my firebase.json:
[image]

Comment: Double check your deployment path @Devika

Comment: May I know which IDE u r using ?

Comment: I am using Flutlab which is an online IDE for flutter .I used cmd for deployment after downloading the sourcecode .

Comment: Ok @Devika, Did you check the deployment path is correct ?

Comment: can you share your `firebase.json` file because there is a possibility you have run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63392550/wrong-page-loading-by-default-on-firebase-link-how-do-i-change-the-default-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue , I shouldn't have overwrite the index.html .Overwriting index.html will produce a default index.html which is created by firebase .So when they ask  `File build/web/index.html already exists. Overwrite?` No should be given .

Answer (score 0):

As I see your in image,it shows your `build/web` folder contains only 2 files in the folder. This is mostly happens if the deployment path incorrect.

[image]

**Follow the steps to sovle the issue**

> 1. Enter `firebase init`.  After running this command it will show the parent `folder path` of your project as in the below image.

[image]

> 2. After that select `Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys` this future to host.
>    And then hit `enter button`

[image]

> 3. This will show you the `public directory` of your project as below

[image]

> 4. After that enter your public directory as  `build/web`.

[image]

> 5. If you do all the above steps correctly while deploying the code, your `build/web` will contains around more than 70 files as the below image

[image]

**I hope this will solve your issue**

Comment: I did everything exactly like the above,but still it redirects to the same page and shows 2 files in build/web while deploying

Comment: If the path is corrct it wont show only 2 files @Devika

Comment: May I know what this deployment path actually means ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKRbn.png

Comment: yes my deployment path is correct .Actually what I did was that after making some changes in the sourcecode using flutlab ,I downloaded the source code into my downloads folder ,and deleted the previous source code folder which I used to deploy at first.Anyway both files habe same name

Comment: No Should I remove  the index.html file in the public folder

Comment: no you should not remove, you should redirect to index.html file

Comment: did u solve the issue ?

Comment: No I didnt ,It still redirects to the default index.html page in public folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251111/discussion-between--and-devika).